# Split function to an array. Type mismatch error #13

Tags: arrays, ms-access, split, vba, type-mismatch

I have a string with multiple email addresses separated by semicolons and want to split them into separate values.

```vb
Dim RecipientArray() As Variant 'I've also tried as string
Debug.Print txtRecipients.Value
RecipientArray = Split(txtRecipients.Value, ";") 'error happens here
For i = 0 To UBound(RecipientArray)
    Debug.Print RecipientArray(i)
Next
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make `RecipientArray` a plain Variant instead of a Variant array.

```vb
'Dim RecipientArray() As Variant 'I've also tried as string
Dim RecipientArray As Variant
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually got it to work as: Dim RecipientArray() As String. I have no idea why that wasn't working before. I tried your solution too out of curiosity and it also worked. Thanks again.